# Change matrix format

Tags: python, r, perl

My file looks like

```
1   11063   upstream_gene_variant
1   13011   intron_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant
1   13289   non_coding_transcript_exon_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant
1   13289   non_coding_transcript_exon_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant&feature_truncation
```

I would like to transform it to the following

```
    1   11063   upstream_gene_variant
    1   13011   intron_variant   non_coding_transcript_variant  
    1   13289   non_coding_transcript_exon_variant    non_coding_transcript_variant
    1   13289   non_coding_transcript_exon_variant  non_coding_transcript_variant  feature_truncation
```

- replcace the **&** with **a tab**
- put the splitted string into separate field in a table

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` if we read the data in `R`.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'V3', '&', 'wide')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
 V2 = c(11063L, 13011L, 
 13289L, 13289L), V3 = c("upstream_gene_variant", 
 "intron_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant", 
 "non_coding_transcript_exon_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant", 
"non_coding_transcript_exon_variant&non_coding_transcript_variant&feature_truncation"
 )), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: also `cbind(df1[, 1:2], read.table(text = gsub('&', '\t', df1$V3), fill = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
text = open(filename).read()
with open(filename, 'w') as write_file:
    write_file.write(text.replace("&", "\t"))
```

Answer (score 0):

python soln:

```
import re

formatted_data = ''
with open('myFile.txt', 'r') as infile:
     for line in infile:
     if '&' in line:
          re.sub(r'[&]*', '\t', line)
     formatted_data += line + '\n'

with open('newData.txt', 'w') as out:
     out.write(formatted_data)
```